# Create a constant bitvector

Tags: c++, z3

I am very new to Z3 and trying to use its bitvector C++ API. As far as I understood, the method bv_val(int n, unsigned sz) in the class context aims to create a bitvector of size sz with value n. 
But why the value n is limited as type int ?. What happens if I create a bitvector of size 10 with a value, e.g. more than 2^64 ?

Would someone give me some suggestions ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since when is 10 more than 2^64?

Comment: I don't know `Z3`, but I take a guess and say "don't fill stuff more than it's capacity". The question is "what do you want to achieve?". We may help you then

Comment: Confusion about whether the size is specified in bits or bytes (or something else)?

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining more detail. Since a bitvector is a "vector of bits", its size is specified in the argument sz (hence its maximum value can be quite large, e.g if sz = 10 then the values possible are located in [-2^79, 2^79-1]), but here its value is specified in the argument n (here it is of type int, namely it must be located in [-2^31, 2^31-1]).

Comment: Ah, my example above is totally wrong. I have been confused between bits and bytes, but you can replace 10 by 80 for the size of sz in the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Z3 C++ API provides the following methods for creating bit-vector values.

```
    expr bv_val(int n, unsigned sz);
    expr bv_val(unsigned n, unsigned sz);
    expr bv_val(__int64 n, unsigned sz);
    expr bv_val(__uint64 n, unsigned sz);
    expr bv_val(char const * n, unsigned sz);
```

For bit-vector values of size greater than UINTMAX64, we must use strings. Example:

```
    expr big = ctx.bv_val("1267650600228229401496703205376", 512);
```

where `ctx` is a Z3 context object.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I did not know that there is also the method `expr bv_val(char const * n, unsigned sz);`.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the only answer you'll get to this question is "Because the devs made it so".

We can really only represent finite quantities in computer science.  When designing an API, the question sometimes comes up as to what the maximum or minimum value of something should be.  In this particular case, the maximum value for `n` seems to be `UINT_MAX` (there's an `unsigned int` overload for the function).

Maybe the devs thought the use-case where `n > UINT_MAX` was unrealistic.  That no one in their right mind would attempt it.

Maybe it's because performing the operation with `n > UINT_MAX` was too taxing on resources (took too long, too much memory).

Maybe it's because there's a way to split this kind of operation in multiple pieces, making the inability to perform it in one large pass a non-issue.

Or maybe someone just didn't think about it and the need to pass `n > UINT_MAX` really exists.  In that case, I believe you can submit an issue on their [bug tracker](http://z3.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

Most likely, it's just because someone thought: "Good Enough".  In any case, this question can't really be answered.